# Can I split describe() on a factor variable?

Tags: r, hmisc

I'd like to describe a response variable according to all the values in a factor variable.

I want to run something like this code

```
library("Hmisc")
describe(mtcars$hp)
```

Except that I want to get a different output by each value of `cyl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `tidy` / `purrr` solution

```r
library(Hmisc)
library(purrr)
mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  purrr::map(~ describe(.x$hp))
#> $`4`
#> .x$hp 
#>        n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd      .05      .10 
#>       11        0       10    0.995    82.64    24.51     57.0     62.0 
#>      .25      .50      .75      .90      .95 
#>     65.5     91.0     96.0    109.0    111.0 
#> 
#> lowest :  52  62  65  66  91, highest:  93  95  97 109 113
#>                                                                       
#> Value         52    62    65    66    91    93    95    97   109   113
#> Frequency      1     1     1     2     1     1     1     1     1     1
#> Proportion 0.091 0.091 0.091 0.182 0.091 0.091 0.091 0.091 0.091 0.091
#> 
#> $`6`
#> .x$hp 
#>        n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd 
#>        7        0        4    0.911    122.3    23.71 
#>                                   
#> Value        105   110   123   175
#> Frequency      1     3     2     1
#> Proportion 0.143 0.429 0.286 0.143
#> 
#> $`8`
#> .x$hp 
#>        n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd 
#>       14        0        9    0.985    209.2    56.69 
#> 
#> lowest : 150 175 180 205 215, highest: 215 230 245 264 335
#>                                                                 
#> Value        150   175   180   205   215   230   245   264   335
#> Frequency      2     2     3     1     1     1     2     1     1
#> Proportion 0.143 0.143 0.214 0.071 0.071 0.071 0.143 0.071 0.071
```

Comment: If I want to split on two variables, can I do `split(.$cyl, .$vs)`

Comment: In that case I would use the "new" `dplyr` `group_split` like this `mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, am) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  purrr::map(~ describe(.x$hp))`

Answer (score 3):

are you looking for

```
lapply(split(mtcars,mtcars$cyl),describe)
```

---

**Edit:** I see you specificallly were looking for the `describe` on on `hp`. You can add `$hp` to the above split, or more simply use

```
tapply(mtcars$hp,mtcars$cyl,describe)
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds. Except it seems in this example like that first `mtcars` should be `mtcars$hp`

Comment: Good attention to detail @Adam, I've updated the answer

Comment: Can I attach this to a dplyr statement? I'd like to do something like mtcars %>% filter(hp > x) %>% {tapply function}

Comment: You can do something like this @Cauder `mtcars %>%
  filter(hp > 100) %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  purrr::map(~ describe(.x$hp))`

Answer (score 1):

You can `group_by` `cyl` and store `describe` object in a list :

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)

new_mtcars <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(data = list(describe(hp)))
new_mtcars
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl data      
#  <dbl> <list>    
#1     4 <describe>
#2     6 <describe>
#3     8 <describe>

new_mtcars$data[[1]]
#hp 
#       n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd      .05      .10 
#      11        0       10    0.995    82.64    24.51     57.0     62.0 
#     .25      .50      .75      .90      .95 
#    65.5     91.0     96.0    109.0    111.0 

#lowest :  52  62  65  66  91, highest:  93  95  97 109 113
                                                                  
#Value         52    62    65    66    91    93    95    97   109   113
#Frequency      1     1     1     2     1     1     1     1     1     1
#Proportion 0.091 0.091 0.091 0.182 0.091 0.091 0.091 0.091 0.091 0.091
```